# Any fairly large/elaborate code samples of Scala with hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, scala

Beyond a simple model, I was hoping if there is maybe a open source project that is written in Scala that uses hibernate, does one exist?

I have seen simple examples so far, but was hoping there were some fairly large scale projects  using hibernate that I can learn from.

Comment: Are you constrained to using Hibernate? Many Scala developers these days eschew ORMs in favour of something more light-weight.

If you have some flexibility here you may like to take a look at something like Slick http://slick.typesafe.com/.

Otherwise, I would imagine a large Scala/Hibernate project would not really be structured so differently from the equivalent large Java/Hibernate project.

Comment: @adamretter I'm looking for hibernate examples.  but if you have a reference to a larger scale slick app that would be interesting also.